# Is mxnet.symbol.Convolution cyclic?

Tags: mxnet

Is the Convolution symbol computed cyclically, i.e., does it assume that the padded input symbol is periodical in all dimensions?

More specifically, if I've got input symbol of dimensions 1x3xHxW, representing an RGB image, and I define a convolution operating on it as below:
conv1 = mxmet.symbol.Convolution(data=input, kernel=(3, 5, 5), pad=(0, 2, 2)...
what the trained filter will look like? I expect it to be composed from linear combinations of 2-D filters operating on each of the color channels R,G,B.

Am I correct?

Comment: 3d convolution is not supported (yet?)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that convolutions in mxnet are 3D: first two dimensions reflect image coordinates, while the third dimension reflects the depth, i.e., the dimension of the feature space. For an RGB image at the input layer, depth is 3 (unless it is a grayscale image that has depth==1). For any other layer, depth is the number of features.

The convolution across the depth dimension is of course cyclical, such that all features of the current layer can affect any feature of the following layer by finding linear combinations that optimize the detection precision.